# What's NODE ID? I'm not talking about pool ID

Tags: stake-pool, cardano-cli, cardano-node

Was setting up script, sendmytip.sh, to update PoolTool with tip and height information.

I noticed this `NODE_ID` value:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## CHANGE THESE TO SUITE YOUR POOL

# your pool id as on the explorer
PT_MY_POOL_ID="xxxx"
# get this from your account profile page on pooltool website
PT_MY_API_KEY="xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxx"
# Your node ID (optional, this is reserved for future use and is not captured yet)
PT_MY_NODE_ID="xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx"
```

It's the last line, and is clearly different from the Pool ID.

Would anyone care to let me know how to find a node id, or explain what they are?

When i read a spec, interface, or proposal, however vague readers are giving a clue. I ask because I did not find one. Interfaces aren’t even told how to handle the property.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the node ID is a variable that has not yet been implemented on Pooltool side so just ignore it at the moment.

***Date : September 26th, 2021***

As there is no mention of this variable yet in the Pooltool official documentation, one can "assume" that this would be an unique ID to identify each relay node of your pool ID? (would it make sense?)

Comment: Thank you, and for all: please don’t downvote in event question has authoritative answer. It is server a purpose until then.